# JS: Efficient algorithm to find number of days until next available game

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm getting tangled in knots trying to find an efficient way to determine the number of days until the next available game in my javascript.

Here are the edges:

- There can be exactly 0 or 1 available games for a given day of the week, for any given "game in the database".
- In the database, available games are represented as 7 digits, a 0 if there is no available game for that day, and a 1 if there is an available game for that day. For example: 0111110 means available games are M-F only. Sunday is the first position, then Monday...ending in Saturday, etc. Another example: 0000001 means that Saturday contains the only available game for this particular "game in the database".
- I want to pass 2 values into a js function and get back "the number of days until there is an available game". Param #1 = "today's day number". 0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday, etc. This is obtained by simply querying the javascript date object. Yes, the function could calculate that internally, but I want it as a param so I can more easily run unit tests and change "today's day number" to whatever I want. Param #2 is the available games, for example 0111110.
- If the next available game is "today", I want the function to return 0. Return 1 for tomorrow, 2 for the day after tomorrow, etc. The smallest number it can return is 0 and the largest is 6. A 6 would mean, for example, today is Sunday and the next available game is Saturday. That is just 1 example. A 6 could also mean today is Wednesday and the next available game is Tuesday. Or if today is Friday and the next available game is Saturday, it should return 1.

Here's what I have tried, and it works until the week cycles from Saturday back to Sunday--at which time it breaks down.

```
function getNumberOfDaysUntilNextAvailableGame(todaysDayNumberInWeek, autoEventDays) {
    // autoEventDays examples: 0000001 (Saturday only) or 0111110 (M-F)
    // returning 0 means the next available game is today - returning 1 means the next available game is tomorrow, etc

    if (autoEventDays.length == 7) {

        var dayCounter = 0;
        var looper = 0;
        while (true) {
            var currentIndexer = parseInt(todaysDayNumberInWeek) + parseInt(dayCounter);

            if (currentIndexer > 6) {
                // circling back from end of week to beginning of week
                todaysDayNumberInWeek = 0;
                currentIndexer = parseInt(todaysDayNumberInWeek) + parseInt(dayCounter);
            }

            var indexValue = autoEventDays.substr(currentIndexer, 1);

            if (indexValue == "1") return dayCounter;

            dayCounter++;
            looper++;

            if (looper > 6) return -1;
        }
    } else {
        console.log("ERROR: Invalid AutoEventDays: " + autoEventDays);
        return -1;
    }
}
```

TEST CASES:

```
// test cases
var numberOfDaysUntilNextAvailableGame = 0;
numberOfDaysUntilNextAvailableGame = getNumberOfDaysUntilNextAvailableGame(6, "0111110");
console.log("today is saturday, next available is monday: " + numberOfDaysUntilNextAvailableGame); // expected result = 2

numberOfDaysUntilNextAvailableGame = getNumberOfDaysUntilNextAvailableGame("1", "0111110");
console.log("today is monday, available games are M-F: " + numberOfDaysUntilNextAvailableGame); // expected result = 0

numberOfDaysUntilNextAvailableGame = getNumberOfDaysUntilNextAvailableGame("2", "0000001");
console.log("today is tuesday, available games are saturday only: " + numberOfDaysUntilNextAvailableGame); // expected result = 4

numberOfDaysUntilNextAvailableGame = getNumberOfDaysUntilNextAvailableGame(3, "1110011");
console.log("today is wednesday, next available is friday: " + numberOfDaysUntilNextAvailableGame); // expected result = 2
```

I could have forced it to work with additional ugly checks, but I'm on the wrong road already. I feel that there's an elegant way to do this with only a few lines of code. Please don't try to "fix" my function on the current bad path - give me a more elegant expression that will always work, and I'll be very appreciative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a new string by [slicing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) at the day of the week and adding the rest to the end, then use [`String#indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to find the first '1'.

```js
const countDays = (day, eventDays) =>
  (eventDays.slice(day) + eventDays.slice(0, day)).indexOf('1');

console.log(countDays(6, '0111110')); // '0'+'011111' --> 2
console.log(countDays(3, '0001000')); // '1000'+'000' --> 0
console.log(countDays(4, '0001000')); // '000'+'0001' --> 6
```